# Unresolved dependency sbt-play-ebean

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, ebean

Here is my **plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.9")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.2.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")
```

and **build.sbt**

```
name := """play-java-starter-example"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs, 
  javaEbean, 
  evolutions
)

libraryDependencies += guice


// Test Database
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194"

// Testing libraries for dealing with CompletionStage...
libraryDependencies += "org.assertj" % "assertj-core" % "3.6.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.awaitility" % "awaitility" % "2.0.0" % Test


// Make verbose tests
testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-v"))
```

and I have next line in **application.conf**

```
ebean.default=["models.*"]
```

but I still get an error

> sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-play-ebean;3.0.0: not found

Comment: which version of sbt are you using? `"sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0"` is available for sbt `0.13.x`, while if you are using sbt `1.0.x` you need `"sbt-play-ebean" % "4.x.y"`. For reference [bintray repo](https://bintray.com/playframework/sbt-plugin-releases/play-ebean)

Comment: @LucaT. thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 5):

On the official documentation

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.0.1")
```

4.0.1 is mentioned but if you check the GitHub link for play beans, this version is not even available, the latest version is 4.0.6

So make sure that you are using the currently available version.

Comment: I am also facing same problem with following configuration.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.2.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.2")